# Grouping by time, but not using a specific table column?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that looks something like this:
ID#  timein  timeout

I want to step through and query the data in 5 minute intervals. At each 5 minute time, I am going to check each ID# to see whether it's logged in or logged out based on the timein/out stamps.

What can I group by to get this effect?

Comment: You mean `GROUP BY id`, so only last login/logout will be seen?

Comment: I was thinking that I would group by the 5 minute time stamp and the ID#. So that the data I end up getting is like: timestamp, ID#, 1 (where 1 is logged in).

Comment: I am trying to get historical data in 5 minute chunks about what ID#s were logged in.

Comment: What do you mean by task? The ID#s are fixed, not auto-incrementing. I am trying to look for the past month or so and for every five minutes, figure out which ID#s were logged in using the time in and time out stamps.

Answer (score 0):

So to get Current timestamp, id and 1 when user logged in use this query

```
SELECT NOW(), id, 1 FROM `Logs` WHERE `timein` > `timeout` AND `timein` BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND NOW()
```

Will return entries like (user logs in few times in 5 mins)

```
2014-09-05 09:14:14, 546, 1
2014-09-05 09:16:34, 546, 1
2014-09-05 09:17:59, 138, 1
```

But isn't there logic problem? If you write to database when user logs in, than what goes to `timeout` column? Better have `id | action | date` and than to get when user logs in

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), date FROM `Logs` WHERE action = `login` ORDER BY date DESC
```

Will return entries like (only log in times)

```
138, 2014-09-05 09:17:59
546, 2014-09-05 09:16:34
```

Comment: Here's the query I've started experimenting with. I need to go through historical data in five minute intervals. I want to end up with a gantt style chart showing all of the IDs that were logged in. In this example I am just trying to get it working for one specific time. I am trying to figure out whether the logic is correct in my where condition.  
`SELECT '2014-08-24 15:00:00', GROUP_CONCAT(id)
    FROM table
    WHERE timein < '2014-08-24 15:00:00'
        AND timeout > '2014-08-24 15:00:00'
    GROUP BY 1`

Comment: To answer your other question, the database pulls back logs from another database. Time in and time out are always populated with the correct log in and log out times.